# JSON Parser in Async Task with ListView

Tags: android, json, listview

I have an this code, i can parse from the XML but im having error on setting up the adapter, can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
public class TestJSON extends Activity{

    public static ListView lv;
    public static ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public static LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_json_view);

        new AsyncInitial().execute();
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        //lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, items));
    }

    private class AsyncInitial extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                try {
                    //if (vid_num <= 0) {
                    // Get a httpclient to talk to the internet
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    // Perform a GET request to YouTube for a JSON list of all the videos by a specific user
                    //https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author="+username+"&v=2&alt=jsonc
                    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/SP86E04995E07F6BA8?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=50&alt=jsonc");
                    // Get the response that YouTube sends back
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    // Convert this response into a readable string
                    String jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
                    // Create a JSON object that we can use from the String
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                    // For further information about the syntax of this request and JSON-C
                    // see the documentation on YouTube http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc.html

                    // Get are search result items
                    JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");

                    // Get the total number of video
                    //String vid_num = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("totalItems");
                    //System.out.println("vid_num-------->"+  vid_num);

                    // Loop round our JSON list of videos creating Video objects to use within our app
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        // The title of the video
                        String title = jsonObject.getJSONObject("video").getString("title");
                        System.out.println("Title-------->"+  title);


                        // The url link back to YouTube, this checks if it has a mobile url
                        // if it doesnt it gets the standard url
                        String url;
                        try {
                            url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("video").getJSONObject("player").getString("mobile");//
                            System.out.println("url-------->"+  url);
                        } catch (JSONException ignore) {
                            url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("video").getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
                            System.out.println("url-------->"+  url);
                        }

                        // A url to the thumbnail image of the video
                        // We will use this later to get an image using a Custom ImageView
                        //String TAG_thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("video").getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");
                        //System.out.println("thumbUrl-------->"+  thumbUrl);

                        String video_id = jsonObject.getJSONObject("video").getString("id");
                        System.out.println("video_id-------->"+  video_id);

                        map.put(title, title);
                        //map.put(url, url);
                        map.put(video_id, video_id);

                        menuItems.add(map); 
                    }

                    adapter = new LazyAdapter(TestJSON.this,menuItems);    
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                //Log.e("Feck", e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                //Log.e("Feck", e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                //Log.e("Feck", e);
                }

                return menuItems;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //super.onPostExecute(result);

                pDialog.dismiss();
            }


    }

}
```

The adapter

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    public LazyAdapter(TestJSON testJSON, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems) {
        activity = testJSON;
        data = menuItems;
        System.out.println("Hash-------->");
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override   
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
       }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //ViewHolder holder;

        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); 
        TextView id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);


        HashMap<String, String> menuItems = new HashMap<String, String>();
        menuItems = data.get(position);

        title.setText(menuItems.get("title"));
        id.setText(menuItems.get("video_id"));

        System.out.println("Adapter Title from Hash-------->"+  title);
        System.out.println("Adapter video_id from Hash-------->"+  id);
        return vi;
    }

}
```

and this is the error on log cat

```
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:867)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4066)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10250)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10205)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:1954)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:502)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:442)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at com.jpact.youtubeapp.TestJSON$AsyncInitial.doInBackground(TestJSON.java:122)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at com.jpact.youtubeapp.TestJSON$AsyncInitial.doInBackground(TestJSON.java:1)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-08 17:46:39.567: E/AndroidRuntime(13049):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: never touch UI thread from background thread. Follow @geet's comment and place your `lv.setAdapter(adapter);` code inside `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code:

```
adapter = new LazyAdapter(TestJSON.this,menuItems);    
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

into the following method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onPostExecute(result);

    pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 adapter = new LazyAdapter(TestJSON.this,menuItems);    
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Updating ui fro `doInBackground` is not possible. this causes the exception.

You need to update in `onPostExecute` or use `runOnUiThread`.

`doInbackground` is invoked on the background thread. so you can't update ui from background thread. Ui should be updated on ui thread.

You can return result in `doInBackground`. The result of doInBackGround computation is a parameter to`onPostExecute` . SO return result in `doInbackground` and update ui in `onPostexecute`.

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
  super.onPostExecute(result);
  pDialog.dismiss();
  adapter = new LazyAdapter(TestJSON.this,result);    
  lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the Adapter in the `doInBackground()` method. The Adapter can only be set from the UI thread.

You can either move your code to the `onPostExecute()` method or use the `runOnUiThread(action)` method.

Answer (score 0):

As i have seeing your code you are trying to set the Adapter for your lazy list in

```
doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    //Do not set your adapter here in this method

}
```

Rather you can set your adapter in

```
onPostExecute(Void result){
adapter = new LazyAdapter(TestJSON.this,menuItems);    
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And remove the line which is responsible for setting the adapter in doInBackground method. Never try to work on UiThread from a background Thread. It will always throw an exception. May be this will help you.